# rails not updating session hash on ajax request without pry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, session-cookies, pry-rails

I'm trying  to develop a  cart system(for a practice e-commerce project) on rails  6.

The  code(explaination):

I have a link with class attribute "add_to_cart_link" then I  use a  jquery to select  the elements with the mentioned class and set a on click listener on them. The click listener send an ajax request to 'shopping_experience/add_to_cart'.The control then moves to "add_to_cart" method inside  shoppingExperience controller.

the problem is that even though the  add_to_cart  method  is executed, it  doesn't update my session hash unless  i use  "binding.pry"(this is a feature  of pry gem which is used  for debugging). during  pry whenever  check the state  of the  hash(session hash)  it's always  what its suppose to be and  changed  when i add some  thing to cart.

here is  my  view template(index.html.erb):

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<%= link_to 'view cart', display_cart_path %>
<h1>Items</h1>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Price</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Category</th>
  <th colspan="3"></th>
</tr>
</thead>

 <tbody>
  <% @items.each do |item| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= item.name %></td>
       <td><%= item.price %></td>
    <td><%= item.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= item.category.title %></td>


    <td><%= link_to 'Show', item %></td>
    <td> <a class="add_to_cart_link"   data-item_id=<%=item.id %> href="#"> add to cart button</a> 
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path(item) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

here  is my custom (myjs.js.erb)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', 'a.add_to_cart_link', function() {
    console.log(this);
    console.log($('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
    var id = $(this).attr("data-item_id")
    console.log(id)
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
         url: 'shopping_experience/add_to_cart',
         data: { item_id: id },     
    })
  });
});
```

add_to cart method:

```
def add_to_cart
  if !session[:current_cart] 
    session[:current_cart] =  {:shex_id => session[:current_cart_id] } 
  end

  #checks if session hash's current cart key doesn't have params[:item_id] key, value pair 
  if  !session[:current_cart].key?(params[:item_id]) 
    # set {units: 1}  as params[item_id] key's  value 

    session[:current_cart][params[:item_id]] = {}
    session[:current_cart][params[:item_id]][:quantity] = 1  
  else
    #else  increment  value  of  quantity

    session[:current_cart][params[:item_id]]["quantity"] = session[:current_cart][params[:item_id]]["quantity"] + 1
    #ShexItem.create(item_id: params[:item_id], shopping_experience_id: session[:current_cart_id] ) 
  end

  binding.pry

  puts(' at to cart method end')
end
```

so  if remove  the  the bindin.pry from the end my session has isn't changed at all and i do get a "at the end of add  to cart method" message  in my terminal(even when i  remove the  binding.pry). this  means that the add to card  method is  indeed  called  but  my session doesn't get updated  and if  use  pry to debug whats wrong  it starts to work. I feel it  might be related using  an ajax  request because  maybe the session doesnt  get  updated  or  refreshed . i really am struggling  with this can anyone help?

here is the github repo: https://github.com/HaroonAzhar/ship-shop (i think the repo is public),

if anyone wants to look up the code more.

Answer (score 0):

So I  got it to work. I saw  a line  on my terminal right after  the  "at the  end  of  at to cart method" message, which said :

```
"No template found for ShoppingExperiencesController#add_to_cart, rendering head :no_content".
```

so I  don't really know  what head :no_content is but  i thought it might have un-do/save  changes made to session by my method. so at the end  of  add_to_cart method i redirected to  index page with

```
redirect_to  '/'
```

still quite  not  sure  why template  not  being  found un-do my changes  to hash, if anyone  could share  some  light  over this in the  comments  that'll be  great! :)